# Replace the question marks with one single word

Tags: knowledge, lateral-thinking

This one needs a lot of lateral thinking

> In the equation below replace all the question marks with one single
>   word (same word at every question mark).
>
> Then show that the equation is correct.

[image]

Comment: Frankly, `NaN` (not a number) busts this whole thing wiiiiide open

Comment: Is it an equation (condition) formulated in some programming language?

Comment: No @z100. Kind of straightforward

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Use ?=ROT to get:
>
>  ROT(ROT5(68))[ROT5(105)]=ROT(ROT5(68))[P]/ROT(ROT5(68))[Q]
>
>  which becomes:
>
>   ROT13[ROT5(105)]=ROT13[P]/ROT13[Q]
>
>  Now the clever bit, 105=CV in Roman numerals, and P->C, Q->D in ROT13:
>
>  ROT13(CV)=C/D
>
>  **PI=Circumference/Diameter**