# Same word on both sides makes it right

Tags: knowledge, lateral-thinking

Insert same one word on both sides (in place of the ?) of the following to make it correct.

(No inserting any math operators or not equal to, > or < signs)

> **? (? V(LXVII)) = ? XIII**

Explain why.

This question is linked to my previous question

[Replace the question mark with one single word](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/90834/replace-the-question-marks-with-one-single-word)

And can serve as a Hint to solve that.

---

Hint:

> Right hand side number is associated with?????

Comment: I am sorry but the same word appears 3 times

Comment: I have edited my function giving this, but it still didn't work am I along the right track or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did not expect this question to take this long to solve

> ? (?V(LXIII)) = ? (? 5(68)) = Rot( Rot5(68))= Rot13 = Rot XIII
>
> Rot or Rotate is the word

Comment: there are mistypings everywhere, or I don`t understand something

Comment: V is 5 (Roman) LXIII is 68 so rot5(68) is 13 (check the net).

Answer (score 0):

**Partial answer:**

So upon looking at this I immediately thought (and still believe I am on the correct page with this) that:

> this is all about roman numerals and that you're looking for a number which is also a word in the English language which would make the equation true!

But there are too many variables so I created a function which you can see [here](https://repl.it/repls/PuzzlingTriangularMethod). <- obviously clicking this link is a spoiler.

Very happy that all my components worked, I went ahead and clicked run only to find that non of my proposed combinations worked. It may be that:

> (a) I have missed out a roman numeral or (more likely) (b) I have missed out a word which can be spelt with roman numerals. I got the list [here](https://www.wordnik.com/lists/words-made-of-roman-numerals) but removed any that required punctuation as no operators are allowed. Feel free to suggest any I could add.

---

Edit: rereading the question I realise it says *same* word, but I still believe my attempt should have given the answer

Comment: Good lateral thinking @bee.  But I will reveal my answer soon if no other answers come in

Comment: @DEEM usually problems are left for quite a while before the answers are revealed. Maybe consider leaving another hint?

Comment: Here is one. Right hand side number is associated with?????

Comment: sg with "success",13 is "unlucky" but also a lucky number, 5(67) is a succession, but  I don`t know:)